# generating ordered sets of integers

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to generate all sets of `N+1` integers `n_j` such that 
`n_0 < n_1 < ... < n_N` where each `n_j` runs over some interval: `n_min <= n_j < n_max`.

My current solution:

```
def generate_partitions(nmin, nmax,N):
    n0 = range(nmin, nmax)
    return  (x for x in itertools.product(n0, repeat=N+1)
             if len(set(x)) == N+1 and list(x) == sorted(x))
```

While it works, it's obviously rather stupid. I'm feeling there should be a better `itertools`-based solution, but I can't figure it out so far, and would appreciate any hints or pointers.

Comment: Your backslashes are redundant; they are not needed when inside matching parenthesis, brackets or curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `itertools.combinations(range(nmin, nmax), N + 1)`?